# Why can't we define a variable just after if statement follows

Tags: java, variables, if-statement

```
public class Foo{    
  public static void main(String []args){  
    int a=10;
    if(a==10)
    int x=20;    
  }
}
```

While compiling above code, an error is thrown at compile.

But, in the below code it is fine. Why?

```
public class Foo{    
  public static void main(String []args){    
    int a=10;    
    if(a==10){    
    int x=20;
    }
  }
}
```

I don't get it. What exactly is happening in these? As I understand, we can write one statement after an if statement without curly braces (compound statement block).

Comment: add the error you're getting on compilation

Comment: Your code looks okay to me, what exactly is the error?

Comment: Foo.java:9: error: not a statement
    int x=20;   
    ^
      Foo.java:9: error: illegal start of expression
    int x=20;
         ^

Comment: @VaibhavShahapure: To improve a question, use the "edit" link rather than comments.

Comment: It's a good question... Wonder why it was downvoted...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For clarity, the problem is here:

```
if(a==10)
    int x=20;
```

...and the error is `error: variable declaration not allowed here`.

It's not allowed there because there is a specific list of statements that are allowed following an `if`; they're detailed in [JLS§14.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-Statement):

- `StatementWithoutTrailingSubstatement`
- `LabeledStatement`
- `IfThenStatement`
- `IfThenElseStatement`
- `WhileStatement`
- `ForStatement`

`StatementWithoutTrailingSubstatement` (the first thing above) includes:

- `Block`
- `EmptyStatement`
- `ExpressionStatement`
- `AssertStatement`
- `SwitchStatement`
- `DoStatement`
- `BreakStatement`
- `ContinueStatement`
- `ReturnStatement`
- `SynchronizedStatement`
- `ThrowStatement`
- `TryStatement`

Note that [`LocalVariableDeclarationStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4) does not appear on that list. Whereas `LocalVariableDeclarationStatement` *is* allowed within [`Block`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-Block), so your second example is fine.

***Why*** doesn't it appear on the list? It's always dangerous to speculate why language designers do what they do. But what the heck: Let's say they allowed it. What does it mean? Is it scoped to just the `if`'s body? That's a bit pointless, isn't it? They it would have no effect other than side-effects from initialization (e.g., `int x = foo();`), and in that case you should just write the side-effect-causing thing (`foo();`). If it *isn't* scoped to just the `if`'s body (it ends up in the containing scope), that's fairly confusing, isn't it? It *looks* like it wouldn't be declared except if the `if`'s condition were true...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first always format your code, so that its easier to read.

I never tried this. But it definitely makes no sense. `int x=20` is dead code, as in an if without { } there is only one command allowed. So you define in this one command a variable that immediately after that is undefined again, as the context of the 'if' is left. And 'x' is only valid in that context of 'if'

```
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String []args){

        int a=10;

        if(a==10)
            int x=20;

    }
}
```

I guess this dead code is seen by the compiler as definitely wrong and unintentional.

Your other example is the same, but the compiler does not notice it.